Using Tomee Embedded with Tomee-<flavor> BOM as dependency manager
I'm trying to use Tomee Embedded in a simple application and I'm having problems setting it up with Microprofile.
I tried to add tomee-plus as dependency manager so I could set the dependencies on Maven easily, but without success.
Here is the pom.xml that I tried:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-plus</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-microprofile</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-microprofile</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

But it doesn't seem to find all the dependencies so I can run the app using:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TomEEEmbeddedApplicationRunner.run(Application.class, args);
}

Am I missing something? Also, is there any documentation of the TomEE embedded usage?
Thanks!
EDIT:
I made it work with the following in my dependencies:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-plume</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

My reasoning is that Tomee-Embedded provides just a simple engine to run the app on Tomee, but if we want to have access to the Jakarta/Microprofile APIs we need to add the dependencies ourselves. Which kind of make sense if I think about it.
Also, the BOM that tomee offers seem more like a wrapper around all dependencies needed for an specific flavour, I can live with that.
Can someone confirm my assumptions?
